# Find SQL Servers using Java

Tags: java, sql-server

This might be a basic question, but I tried googling it and couldn't find an answer.

I need to make a list of all the SQL Servers on a network.  This is very easy to do using the .NET framework (System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator), but is there also a relatively simple way to do this in java as well?  While I was doing my research, I came across the possibility of listening in at different ports, but that seemed un-user friendly.  Any ideas?

Thank you all so much.

Comment: The default port is 1433, but it's anybody's guess for multiple instances on the same host.

Comment: @OMG Ponies osql.exe and SqlDataSourceEnumerator are aware of that though SqlDataSourceEnumerator shows only servers that boradcasting itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
osql -L
```

and parse output.

Comment: I'm a newbie in sql. Can you give me some more information or a place to get more information?

Comment: osql.exe is a command line tool. just search it on your hdd and execute with -L switch

Comment: Here is the how to: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3397981/Scanning-the-network-for-SQL-Server.htm  I don't think you can redistribute osql.exe however.

Comment: SQL Servers have to make themselves available for browsing by running the SQL Server Browser Service so it's not a lock that you will find them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx

In addition, if a server is hidden by running in Shared Memory mode you won't be able to connect to it remotely.

So your real question may be: how do I query the SQL Server Browser Service from Java?

Comment: so now that I know what my question is, how do I use sql server browser from java?