# Is it possible to list all available SQL Servers on a network using Java?

Tags: java, sql-server, database-connection

I have found several answers to this question but ALL of them are answered using C#. Most of them use the following code to solve the problem:

```
SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
System.Data.DataTable myDataTable = instance.GetDataSources();
```

It seems pretty solid, but that class doesn't exist in java that I know of and since I have no experience on the subject I don't know a counterpart for java, so my question is: Is there a way to do this (list all available sql servers on the network) using JAVA code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find SQL Servers using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223465/find-sql-servers-using-java)

Comment: Define "on a network"?

Comment: in the intranet, specifically